# Overriding a procedure with 'nopass' attribute in Fortran

Tags: fortran

Suppose I have

```
type :: type1

    contains

    procedure, nopass :: proc => proc_type1

end type type1

type, extends (type1) :: type2

    contains

    procedure, nopass :: proc => proc_type2

end type type2
```

What happens if I do `call instanceOfType2%proc()`? Although this compiles I strongly suspect that `proc_type1` will not be overriden by `proc_type2` as they have the same signature and the compiler cannot establish which of them I want to call. Is that right?

Then I guess what I need to do is to avoid the `nopass` attribute in this case. Or is there any other way?

Can someone please confirm or explain? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nopass is not the same as nonoveridable. It is also very easy just test your code and see what happens.

The compiler can easily establish which of them the call, he has the dynamic type of the instance you use to call the type bound procedure. It then searches in the [table of type bound procedures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) which one is the right to call during the dynamic dispatch.

Comment: Aha, but then why is there the restriction that the overriding and overridden procedures have to have the same signature except the type of the passed dummy argument? The compiler could do what you say even if the signatures differed. This confused me.

Comment: The call must make sense for all possible dynamic types. Don't confuse that with static dispatch - generic procedures, those are completely different.

Comment: I think I got it now. That was a helpful clarifying comment.